# how to check a cell in particular coulmn in datgridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox

i have following method to display a combobox in datagridview in window form .

how i pass argument in it, when their is control over any cell of particular column and under which event of datagridview .

```
private void Show_Combobox(int iRowIndex, int iColumnIndex)
{
    // DESCRIPTION: SHOW THE COMBO BOX IN THE SELECTED CELL OF THE GRID.
    // PARAMETERS: iRowIndex - THE ROW ID OF THE GRID.
    //             iColumnIndex - THE COLUMN ID OF THE GRID.

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int Width = 0;
    int height = 0;

    // GET THE ACTIVE CELL'S DIMENTIONS TO BIND THE COMBOBOX WITH IT.
    Rectangle rect = default(Rectangle);
    rect = dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(iColumnIndex, iRowIndex, false);
    x = rect.X + dataGridView1.Left;
    y = rect.Y + dataGridView1.Top;

    Width = rect.Width;
    height = rect.Height;

    comboBox1.SetBounds(x, y, Width, height);
    comboBox1.Visible = true;
    comboBox1.Focus();
}
```

thanks in advance ....

Comment: i have two questions for you:   A) why don't you use the `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` instead of what you're doing? and B) what exactly are you trying to do to the `ComboBox` or the `Cell` again? could you please clear that up?

Comment: @niklas , datagridviewcombooxcell does not allow user to enter the text and accept values that are not in combobox list . if i can accomplish these issues with datagridviewcoboboxcell , then let me know .... thanks

Comment: it does. check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can in fact use `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` for your purpose.

here is an example on how to :
in order to do that, you can cast the control to a combobox on the event of the combobox that suits you best.

i have chosen `EdittingControlShowing` as it is raised after the control is shown i.e the combobox has been clicked so it would rase its drop down method:

```
private void gridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control.GetType() == typeof(DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl))
    {
        ((ComboBox)e.Control).DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
    }
}
```

this way you will let the user enter his/her own value if the preset value is not present in the `ComboBox`'s `Items`.in order to do that you can take the following approach using the `CellValidating` Event:

```
if (gridView1.CurrentCell.IsInEditMode)
{
    if (gridView1.CurrentCell.GetType() == typeof(DataGridViewComboBoxCell))
    {
        if (!((DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)gridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex]).Items.Contains(e.FormattedValue))
        {
            ((DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)gridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex]).Items.Add(e.FormattedValue);
        }
    }
}
```

this will add the input to the items of the `ComboBox` cell in this case.

Comment: thanks , but how to change "DataGridViewComboBoxColumn" default structure to simple text box style like ,so that combobox shows only when cell is active and save the newly entered value in datagridview's cell , not in combobox cell's list ...

Comment: But the example is pretty clear you just have to control the flow :s