# display combobox in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I am new to  programming...

I want to display  combobox in a particular column as soon as user starts to enter the text in that column or a cell got selected in that column and it shows the combobox along with its  list ,also let to user to type  their own values in that cell and display that value as cell text   . Currently available comboboxcell doesn't have such faculties . how can i accomplish such task .

any reference to to this ..

thanks in advance ...

Comment: Please provide some code which you have done till now.

Comment: You want the combobox values to be based on what?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/43038016/3956100